# Getting text from UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I'm trying to get text from an alert view and add it to my mutable array to list in a table view. I realize there is a similar question that was posted a few months ago, but I dont understand how to utilize the given answer.

```
-(IBAction)insert {
    UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [dialog setDelegate:self];
    [dialog setTitle:@"Enter Name"];
    [dialog setMessage:@" "];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

    UITextField *nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
    [nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [dialog addSubview:nameField];
    [dialog show];

    [data addObject:[nameField text]];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
```

However my app crashes because it says I'm attempting to insert a nil object at index 0. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Ok I think I'm missing a method to handle the alertview. So I found this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]) {
        return;
    }
    else if([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Ok"]) {
        [data addObject:nameField.text];

    }
```

Now I just need to connect the pieces, but not sure how.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A common mistake that people make when using a `UIAlertView` is that they think that sending it a `show` message will block the main thread.  It does not.  Your code continues to execute, even though there is an alert on the screen.  Thus, no value exists for the `UITextField` that you have passed in.

What you need to do is implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate` in your `UIViewController` to grab whatever a user has entered into the text field.  That said, you still have to check for a `nil` value, because if you don't type anything in, the `text` value will be `nil`.

UPDATE: This answer was posted before Apple created an API for adding a `UITextField` to an alert through the `UIAlertViewStyle`.  Here is the updated code, borrowed from @matt

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter Name"
                                                message:@"  "   
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
```

Then, in the `UIAlertViewDelegate` call back:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSString *name = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        // Insert whatever needs to be done with "name"
    }
}
```

Comment: My app is a window based application. Does this matter?

Comment: @f-Prime No, it does not matter.  We are traversing the hierarchy of the UIAlertView.

Comment: Ok so what should my complete code look like? My add method plus your clickedButtonAtIndex method and it should work? Do I have to call clickedButtonAtIndex in my add method? Cuz as it is now, its not working

Comment: Only thing you missed here is reloading the table view.

Comment: This answer is not correct. You must set the correct UIAlertViewStyle, not add a subview. This is dangerous and not portable. See @Matt answer below.

Comment: @mrplants This answer was given before there was an API for adding a text field.  That said, thanks for the heads up so I can update my answer!

Answer (score 27):

You don't need to add your own text field to the AlertView but instead set the appropriate style

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter Name"
                                                message:@"  "   
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
```

Then access the entered text after OK (button 1) was pressed

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSString *name = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        // name contains the entered value
    }
}
```

Comment: i Got name is nil in IOS 11

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to add a `UITextView` on a `UIAlertView` or else Apple might reject your app.

I already used the same kind of functionality in my app. But Apple **REJECTED MY APP** due to the use of `UITextView` in `UIAlertView`.

Comment: wtf i used many case in app, one app published? Did you do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`– alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` is a delegate method of UIAlertView. Just add the method you defined in your edit to your controller implementation and you should be good to go, since you already set the controller to be the AlertView's delegate.

Also add  to your class header, to avoid any delegate related warnings, ie:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
...
};
```

Don't forget to remove `[data addObject:[nameField text]];` and `[mainTableView reloadData];` from the insert method.

Comment: Ok I did that but I get a "namefield undeclared" error in the clickedButtonAtIndex method

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert title" 
                                                  message:@"alert message" 
                                                 delegate:self 
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
[myAlert addTextFieldWithValue:nil label:@"<place holder>"];
[[myAlert textField] setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[[myAlert textField] becomeFirstResponder];
[myAlert show];
[myAlert release];
myAlert = nil;
```

No need to add a custom textfield. You can directly add using addTextFieldWithValue method.

Comment: UIAlertView doesn't seem to have a method `addTextFieldWithValue:label:`