# Adding TextField to UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I need to add a `TextField` to an `UIAlertView`. I understand that apple discourage this approach. So is there any library that i could make use of to add a `TextField` to a `UIAlertView` look-alike frame ?

Answer (score 69):

For iOS5:

```
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Please enter someth" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
av.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[av textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;
[av show];
```

Also, you 'll need to implement `UITextFieldDelegate`, `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocols.

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately the only official API for this is iOS 5 and up, it's a property called `alertViewStyle` which can be set to the following parameters:

```
UIAlertViewStyleDefault
UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput
UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput
UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput
```

`UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` being the one you want.

Messing with the view hierarchy as described above is strongly discouraged by Apple.

Comment: I have to create this for iOS 4 and 5. So are you aware of any other library where i could use

Answer (score 6):

I'm using [BlockAlertsAndActionSheets](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tweetbot-like-uialertview-and-uiactionsheet-replacement) instead of the Apple components for AlertViews and ActionSheets as I prefer the blocks-approach. Also contains a `BlockTextPromptAlertView` in the source, which might be what you want. You can replace the images of that control to get the Apple-style back.

[Project on gitgub](https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets)

[Tutorial which gets you started](http://blog.codecropper.com/2012/01/replicating-tweetbot-alerts-and-action-sheets/)

Example:

```
- (IBAction)newFolder:(id)sender {
    id selfDelegate = self;
    UITextField                 *textField;
    BlockTextPromptAlertView    *alert = [BlockTextPromptAlertView  promptWithTitle :@"New Folder"
                                                                    message         :@"Please enter the name of the new folder!"
                                                                    textField       :&textField];
    [alert setCancelButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel" block:nil];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Okay" block:^{
        [selfDelegate createFolder:textField.text];
    }];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)createFolder:(NSString*)folderName {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Can you show me an example that uses `BlockTextPromptAlertView `. I am under the impression that developers are not allowed to add any textfields etc to UIAlertView.

Comment: You're right with your impression. That's why BlockAlertsAndActionSheets is **not** using UIAlertView at all, it's a completely independent implementation without any private API's being used. I don't have access to my sources right now, but can update my answer with an code sample in some hours.

Comment: Is there a way where i could stop the animation ? (Th bouncing effect)

Comment: If you would like to change the way the control is animated, try searching for `animateWithDuration` in BlockAlertView.m and BlockTextPromptAlertView.m

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                 message:@"\n\n"
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil] autorelease];
CGRect rect = {12, 60, 260, 25};
UITextField *dirField = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:rect] autorelease];
dirField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[dirField becomeFirstResponder];
[alert addSubview:dirField];

[alert show];
```

Comment: I think Apple discourage your approach.

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 8 `UIAlertView` has been deprecated in favor of [`UIAlertController`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32000905/883413), which adds support for adding `UITextField`s using the method:

```
- (void)addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:(void (^)(UITextField *textField))configurationHandler;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32000905/883413) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your title here!" message:@"this gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[myAlertView addSubview:testTextField];
[myAlertView show];
[myAlertView release];
```

Follow this [link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1704-uitextfield-inside-uialertview.html) for detail.

Comment: Yes, your code works. But Apple discourages this approach, as its using private APIs. SO is there any other way i could solve this ?

Comment: @anonymous The OP refers to that sentence from the docs: The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Answer (score 1):

first of All Add UIAlertViewDelegate into ViewController.h File like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController : UITableViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>

@end
```

and than Add Below Code where you wants to alert Display,

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                            message:@"Message"
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
```

and it's delegate method which returns what input of UItextField

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
NSLog(@"%@", [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this... http://iosdevelopertips.com/undocumented/alert-with-textfields.html **this is private api and if you use it for app in appstore it might get rejected but it is fine for enterprise development.**

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i am hoping to publish my app to appstore :S

Comment: than I won't advise you should implement this.

Answer (score 0):

adding to answer from 'Shmidt', the code to capture text entered in UIAlertView is pasted below (thank you 'Wayne Hartman' [Getting text from UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560346/getting-text-from-uialertview))

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        self.userNumber = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        if (self.userNumber) {
            // user enetered value
            NSLog(@"self.userNumber: %@",self.userNumber);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"null");
        }

    }
}
```